# Reactjs error when compiling the front end

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

The above is my code
I am facing an error when I compile:Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? (53:4)

I am trying to compile in the front end using yarn start, but I face this error. any idea to solve?

Comment: Add a `div` or something before and after the `customerList` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you got correctly, after every return make sure your elements are wrapped properly. You didn't wrapped component after mapping customerList.

Answer (score 0):

closing tags are wrongly placed.
**Improvemeents:** since you are using arrow function you do not need to use return. It can be just *`.map((val,index) => (<div key={index}>{val}</div>))`*.